# How do I control the speed of a universal AC motor and measure the voltage and current flowing through it?

Tags: motor, rms, drill, universal-motor

It is desired to be able to control the speed of my rotary drill as well as measure the average torque (or is RMS torque a thing?) of the universal AC motor.
I am using this torque equation: τ = (I * V * E *60) / (rpm * 2π).

My best guess is to measure when the AC 120V signal crosses zero, and fire a Triac to let current flow to the drill. In fact, here is a module that would do it all for me: [https://www.amazon.com/RobotDyn-controller-control-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B072K9P7KH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072K9P7KH). The issue with this is it will most likely be fried if I run the drill anywhere near max power. Not to mention the Arduino library is sub-par.

Another idea I have is to use a solid state relay, and just have it on 50% of the time- maybe turning on and off ~100 times per second, if that is even possible. However, the voltage depends on time and if the relay is turned on when the AC signal is at 0, it will be a different RMS voltage than if the relay is turned on when the AC signal is at its maximum. So maybe I still need a zero cross detector, and then fire the relay accordingly. Then I could use some math and find RMS voltage from there, using these equations: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-calculate-rms-voltage-from-triac-phase-angle.572668/.

I have a current sensor in series with the drill, so current can be measured easily.

Is this the best way to go about it? I am no electrical engineer so this is all very new to me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What type of drill is it?  Drill press?  Does it use belts or gearing?

Comment: What about connecting a filament bulb of suitable power in series? Will slow the drill and no burning. Short circuit that bulb by triac pulse wise to get suitable rpm. Just an idea.

Comment: A relay at that speed isnot going to work.

Comment: It is a rotary hammer drill. What is the switching speed of a solid state relay? Also I don't think a bulb could take that much power on...